# Django expecting primary key I don't have

Tags: python, html, django, http, post

I am getting an exception:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ljrh'
```

from this code trying to create an entry in a model:

```
day = itemize(value, getday(strip(key)))
add = Reoccurring(request.user.username, strip(day.Day), strip(day.N), strip(day.S), strip(day.E))
add.save()
```

I went back in and created my own primary key and supplemented it with an integer value and it fixed the error..it seems like it is expecting my first value to be a primary key..I was under the impression if one is not provided that django would auto create a primary key..

here is my model:

```
class Reoccurring(models.Model):
    Username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Day = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    Summary = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Start = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    End = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s %s %s %s %s" % (self.Username, self.Day, self.Summary, self.Start, self.End)
```

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it seems like it is expecting my first value to be a primary key.

It is.

> I was under the impression if one is not provided that django would auto create a primary key.

It did.

But those are different "it"s. The latter is Django's ORM, whereas the former is the model's **constructor**.

```
add = Reoccurring(Username=request.user.username, Day=strip(day.Day), Summary=strip(day.N), Start=strip(day.S), End-strip(day.E))
```

Comment: Ah thank you, I did not understand the distinction, answer marked